# Ternary to If-Else statement

Tags: ios, if-statement

I wrote a code long back using ternary operators, can someone help me in expanding this to if-else statement

```
frameSize.height = (frameSize.height>15)?((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)?70.0:70.0) + (lines*15) + SMALL_MARGIN:100;

  if (frameSize.height>15) { 
       if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
          frameSize.height = 70.0 + (lines*15) + SMALL_MARGIN;
       } else {
           frameSize.height = 70.0 + (lines*15) + SMALL_MARGIN; 
         } 
       } else {
           frameSize.height = 100.0;
     }
```

Comment: What does your attempt look like?

Comment: does it work? Any chance you could add this to your question so that it can be laid out better. Makes it easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm pretty sure there's a `(` and a `)` more..

i think this is the code you are looking for:

```
if (frameSize .height > 15) {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        frameSize.height = 70.0;
    } else {
        frameSize.height = 70.0 + (lines*15) + SMALL_MARGIN);
    }
} else {
    frameSize.height = 100;
}
```

hope this helps :-)

Comment: This is what I had to code originally. Don't know what came to my mind and I wrote a ternary statement

Comment: well, you can do it with a ternary statement as well. But this way is much more easy to read :-)

Answer (score 0):

`(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)?70.0:70.0)` will always return 70.0. Pretty sure you can scrap this logic and after that it starts looking pretty simple.